# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglueml'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrameCollection
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglueml.transforms import FillMissingValues
```

For some reason I am getting the error,

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglueml'

When I am trying to run my AWS Glue Job. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

awsglueml does not work on Glue 3.0. You may need to change it to Glue 2.0 and Python 3

Or you can use COALESCE in SQL to fill Miss values if you don't want to change Glue version